# Posting a Text input or select option to the database depending on which one is chosen

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, input

this is a pretty basic question I am just struggling to get the correct input in the database.

In the circumstances that a drop-down box doesn't have the required selection, how can I allow a user to input their own selection and post this to the database?

For example if I have the following as a rough example:

Add a new category: `<input type="text" name="category" /></br>`

Or select one of the following categories:

```
<select name="category"><option>""</option><option>Category 1</option><option>Category 2</option></select>
```

How can I write the required code in the `$sql` statement to post either the user's own category, or if left blank; the category from the option selected?

I am asking the question as I am writing in PHP and wonder if there may be a easier option using Javascript or altering the `$sql` statement?

Any help would be great, I would appreciate answers in code so I can see more clearly.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you have so far? I assume you have the DB insert part figured out?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, yes the `$sql` statement is executing fine, it is just posting the select options though, however if these select options are left blank, I would like it to post the text input instead. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a simple `if..else` statement.

```
if(!empty($_POST['select_box'])) 
// something like $input = $_POST['select_box'] 
elseif(!empty($_POST['input_box']))
//[...]
```

And of course, your default `<option>` in your select box should look like:

`<option value="" selected>Default(blank) option</option>`

Comment: Thanks rm-vanada, all sorted, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot name both your input field and your select box "category" if in the same form. One will always override the other. Set a default value to your input field and name it category1. Similarly, name your select box category2.

Then, in your PHP:

```
if $category1 == "": $category = $_POST['category1']; 
else: $category = $_POST['category2'];
```

Comment: Hi Noble, yes I was aware that that would happen, I will try it with an if/else statement. Pretty new to this, so just trying to find the best and correct way. Thank you for your example! Much appreciated!

Comment: I just realized that in my array solution you will still have to check if category[0] is equal to "", so it isn't really a solution. Anyway, try it out, add to your question, and accept the best answer once it's fixed.

Comment: Just giving them both a try now, the input box is posting OK but the select option isn't? Will have a look again now and see if I can find the problem. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: All sorted, I managed to get it working with rm-vanda's solution, but thank you for all your help! +1